# SSIS Package Fail - Login Failed

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS package pulling in a table and merging with some other data.  The additional table is held in a different server (SQL02) to the one running the SSIS package (SQL01).  Run's fine when I execute it in Visual Studio, however when I deploy it to SQL01 and execute I get the below error;

> Login Failed for user 'DOM\SQL2016'

If I remove the SQL02 table from the SSIS package it will run fine on SQL01, so it looks like some sort of access issue between the two servers.

SQL01 is SQL2016, SQL02 is SQL2008 r2

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: the user DOM\SQL2016 would need to be granted access to the database on SQL02 server.  When executing in visual studio it is making that connection as you and you have access.  When deployed and executed via an agent job it makes the connection either as the account running the SQL Agent Service on SQL01 or as a proxy account depending on how job step is configured and if you use proxy accounts.

Comment: For this kind of process we usually define one user (Like "AgentUser" or "ProxyUser") who is granted all required privileges on all servers. During the execution on the server (Agent Job) we define this user in "execute as...".

Comment: Thanks Tim, worked a treat.  I should have been able to figure out that one!